# Simulated dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, simulation

I'm simulating another dataset here, and am stuck again!

Here's what I want to do:

200 observations, with 90 independent variables (mean 0, sd 1)

the equation to create y is: y = 2x_1 + ... + 2x_30 - x_31 - ... - x_60 + 0*x_61 + ... + 0*x_90 + mu
(In other words, the first 30 x values will have a coefficient of 2, next 30 values have coefficient of -1 and last 30 values have coefficient of 0). mu is also a random generated normal variable with mean 0, sd 10.

Here's what I have so far:

```
set.seed(11)
n <- 200
mu <- rnorm(200,0,10)
p1 <- for(i in 1:200){
   rnorm(200,0,1)
       }
p2 <- cbind(p1)
p3 <- for(i in 1:90){
   if i<=30, y=2x
      if i>30 & i<=60, y=-x
         if i>60 & i<=90, y=0x
             }
```

I'm still learning many aspects of R, so I'm pretty sure the code has much wrong with it, even in terms of syntax. Your help would really be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(mvtnorm)
coefs <- rep(c(2, -1, 0), each=30)
mu <- rnorm(200, 0, 10)
m <- rep(0, 90) # mean of independent variables
sig <- diag(90) # cov of indep variables
x <- rmvnorm(200, mean=m, sigma=sig) # generates 200 observations from multivariate normal 
y <- x%*%coefs + mu
```

In case, if you are not comfortable with linear-algebra

```
n <- 200
coefs <- rep(c(2, -1, 0), each=30)
mu <- rnorm(n, 0, 10)
x <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=90) # initializes the indep.vars
for(i in 1:90){
  x[, i] <- rnorm(200, 0, 1)
}
y <- rep(NA, n) # initializes the dependent vars
for(i in 1:n){
  y[i] = sum(x[i,]*coefs) + m[i]
}
```

`x[i,]*coefs` gives exactly  `(2*x_1,..., 2*x_30, -x_31,...,- x_60,0*x_61,...,0*x_90)` because `*` is element-wise operation.

You'd better learn the rudimentaries of `R`, before actually doing something with it.

Comment: can you please explain this a bit further in your answer? I'm not entirely sure how you got to some of these codes. Or is there a simpler way to do it without the package, and just for loops?

Comment: Since they're all independent, instead of using `rmvnorm` you can just do `x <- replicate(n = 90, expr = rnorm(200))`.

Comment: @ExperimenteR, thanks for the help with the for loops. That makes much more sense to me. I think I was trying to get R to do too much in creating my loops, and of course the syntax was all off. Thanks again.